# Filling Float buffer in Metal

Tags: ios, memory, metal

**Problem:**

I need to fill a `MTLBuffer` of `Float`s with a constant value — say `1729.68921`. I also need it to be as fast as possible.

Therefore I'm prohibited from filling the buffer on the CPU side (i.e. getting `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` from the `MTLBuffer` and assigning in serial manner).

**My approach**

Ideally I'd use [`MTLBlitCommandEncoder.fill()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400761-fill), however AFAIK it's only capable to fill a buffer with `UInt8` values (given that `UInt8` is 1 byte long and `Float` is 4 bytes long, I can't specify arbitrary value of my `Float` constant).

So far I can see only 2 options left, but both seem to be overkill:

1. create another buffer `B` filled with the constant value and copy its contents into my buffer via `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`
2. create a `kernel` function that'd fill the buffer

**Questions**

What's the fastest way of filling `MTLBuffer` of `Float`s with a 
constant value?

Comment: if you need that constant on the GPU, the fastest option is to create that constant inside your kernel function and use it locally, instead of sending one from the CPU via a buffer.

Comment: @Marius I should have clarified why I need to fill the buffer: I have a loop in which I compute stuff. At the beginning of the loop I need my buffer to be initialized to some constant value. Later in the loop I assign into *some locations* of the buffer different values. The locations are different in each loop.

Comment: Are you *sure* that using the CPU is slower? Are you aware of `memset_pattern4()` and that it is likely to be optimized beyond a naive implementation of your own?

Comment: @KenThomases thanks for pointing out `memset_pattern4()` – I didn't know it existed. At first I considered `memset()`, but like `MTLBlitCommandEncoder.fill()` it also fills just by 1 byte, so I avoided filling the buffer myself in a loop on the CPU and didn't even bothered to test CPU-fill against GPU-fill.

Comment: I benchmarked a naive CPU fill loop and found that a compute kernel was at least twice as fast in the scenarios I tested. Still, I wouldn't rule out that it might be faster in some situations, especially if you can wrap a page-aligned allocation instead of taking a copy when creating the buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a compute shader that writes to multiple buffer elements from each thread was the fastest approach in my experiments. This is hardware-dependent, so you should test on the full range of devices you expect the app to be deployed on.

I wrote two compute shaders: one that fills 16 contiguous array elements without checking against the array bounds, and one that sets a single array element after checking against the length of the buffer:

```
kernel void fill_16_unchecked(device float *buffer  [[buffer(0)]],
                              constant float &value [[buffer(1)]],
                              uint index            [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        buffer[index * 16 + i] = value;
    }
}

kernel void single_fill_checked(device float *buffer         [[buffer(0)]],
                                constant float &value        [[buffer(1)]],
                                constant uint &buffer_length [[buffer(2)]],
                                uint index                   [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (index < buffer_length) {
        buffer[index] = value;
    }
}
```

If you know that your buffer count will always be a multiple of the thread execution width multiplied by the number of elements you set in the loop, you can just use the first function. The second function is a fallback for when you might dispatch a grid that would otherwise overrun the buffer.

Once you have two pipelines built from these functions, you can dispatch the work with a pair of compute commands as follows:

```
NSInteger executionWidth = [unchecked16Pipeline threadExecutionWidth];
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[computeEncoder setBuffer:buffer offset:0 atIndex:0];
[computeEncoder setBytes:&value length:sizeof(float) atIndex:1];
if (bufferCount / (executionWidth * 16) != 0) {
    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:unchecked16Pipeline];
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:MTLSizeMake(bufferCount / (executionWidth * 16), 1, 1)
                   threadsPerThreadgroup:MTLSizeMake(executionWidth, 1, 1)];
}
if (bufferCount % (executionWidth * 16) != 0) {
    int remainder = bufferCount % (executionWidth * 16);
    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:checkedSinglePipeline];
    [computeEncoder setBytes:&bufferCount length:sizeof(bufferCount) atIndex:2];
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:MTLSizeMake((remainder / executionWidth) + 1, 1, 1)
                   threadsPerThreadgroup:MTLSizeMake(executionWidth, 1, 1)];
}
[computeEncoder endEncoding];
```

Note that doing the work in this manner will not necessarily be faster than the naive approach that just writes one element per thread. In my tests, it was 40% faster on A8, roughly equivalent on A10, and 2-3x slower (!) on A9. Always test with your own workload.